# How to convert this integral to a contour integral over the unit circle?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, contour-integration

How do you convert this integral into a contour integral over the unit circle (such that you can use the residue theorem)? For context, this is to determine the coefficient $b_n$ in a Fourier series.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\text{sin}(n\theta) d\theta\ = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{sin}(\theta)}{5+4\text{cos}(\theta)}\text{sin}(n\theta) d\theta$$
where $$n=1,2,3,\ldots$$

How should I approach this? Namely, I know I can convert $\text{sin}(\theta)$ to $\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}=\frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{2i}$ and similarly for $\text{cos}(\theta)$, but I am stumped by how to deal with the $\text{sin}(n\theta)$ and namely the $n$.

I have tried using the above approach such that $\text{sin}(n\theta)=\frac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{2i}=\frac{z^n-\frac{1}{z^n}}{2i}$. However I am unsure how to find the residue after simplifying everything. After simplifying, we have poles at -2, -1/2, and 0 (order n+1), of which -1/2 and 0 are enclosed in the unit circle. Using the limit approach to find the residue for the pole at 0 with order n+1, we take the nth derivative and find the limit of that as z approaches 0:
$$\text{Res}(f,0)=\frac{1}{n!}\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} \frac{(z-1)(z+1)(z^n-1)(z^n+1)}{(z+2)(z+\frac{1}{2})}$$

I am unsure how to do this part specifically. Is this the right approach? Did I mess something up?

Comment: try the same trick: $\sin(n\theta)=\frac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{2i}=\frac1{2i}\left(z^n-\frac1{z^n}\right)$

Comment: Thanks. I’ve tried that already but then I’m unsure how to find the residue. I.e., using the limit approach to find the residue for the pole at 0 with order n+1, we have to take the nth derivative and find the limit of that as z approaches 0:
$\text{Res}(f,0)=\frac{1}{n!}\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} \frac{(z-1)(z+1)(z^n-1)(z^n+1)}{(z+2)(z+\frac{1}{2})}$

Comment: I amended my original post to include this and provided more context.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to evaluate the integral in this way. Let $z = e^{i \theta}$, then 
$$g(z) = f(\theta) \sin(n \theta) \, (-i e^{-i \theta}) =
\frac i 8 (z^{n - 1} - z^{- n - 1}) \left(
 1 - \frac 1 {2 z + 1} - \frac 2 {z + 2} \right), \\
\operatorname* {Res}_{z = 0} g(z) =
-\frac i 8 [z^n] \left(
 1 - \frac 1 {2 z + 1} - \frac 2 {z + 2} \right).$$